# rails: session is nilClass when cross controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

there

here is the code, in session_store.rb

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_blog_session'.
```

I use the cookie_store.

```
class HouseController < ApplicationController
  def browser
        session[:go_controller] = "house"
        session[:go_action] = "browser"
        @house=House.last
  end
class HouseController < ApplicationController
  def browser
        session[:go_controller] = "house"
        session[:go_action] = "browser"
        @house=House.last
  end

  def commercial
        session[:current_user_id] = nil
  end

  def rent
        session[:current_user_id] = "chendong"
        @house=House.last
  end

  def search

  end

end
```

in House Controller, I can set session correctly in commercial and rent action.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
        def sell
                if session[:current_user_id] == nil  then
                        session[:go_controller] = "user"
                        session[:go_action] = "sell"
                        redirect_to controller:"user", action:"session"
                end
        end
```

But in another controller (in the same rails app), in the sell action, `session` is a nilClass. Because when I click the House controller rent action to set the `session[:current_user_id]` and then click the User controller sell action, an error occur

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

in line

```
if session[:current_user_id] == nil  then
```

Comment: Add `raise method(:session).source_location.inspect` and paste a result. I have a feeling you overrode the method.

Comment: In house controller the inspect value is `["/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_controller/metal.rb", 129]` , and in user controller the inspect value is `["/home/worker/WebRoot/blog/app/controllers/user_controller.rb", 32]`, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

First off. Don't spread your authentication logic all across your controllers. It's a disaster waiting to happen. And don't misuse the session for pagination for example. Use query params primarily - and the session secondarily!

```
class SessionsHelper
  def sign_in!(user)
    reset_session
    session[:current_user_id] = user.id
  end

  def sign_out!
    reset_session
  end

  # @return [User|Nil]
  def current_user
    @user ||= User.find(session[:current_user_id])
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def is_signed_in?(user)
     user == current_user
  end
end
```

Even better would be to use [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) which does this on the Rack layer.
We then want to add these methods to all our controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SessionsHelper
end
```

We can now refactor our controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def sell
    unless current_user
      redirect_to controller: "user", action: "session"
    end
  end
end
```

But we are not done! We should handle what happens when a user is not authenticated in a better way:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  class NotAuthenticated < StandardError; end
end
```

---

```
class ApplicationController < ActiveRecord::Base

   include SessionsHelper
   before_action :authenticate!

   rescue_from User::NotAuthenticated, with: :deny_access

   private 
     def authenticate!
       raise User::NotAuthenticated unless signed_in?
     end

     def deny_access
       redirect_to controller: "user", action: "session" 
     end
end
```

You might notice here that we are breaking everything since every controller action now requires the user to be signed in! But using opt out security is a good practice since it removes the chance that you left a route unsecured by omission.

So instead you can use `skip_before_action :authenticate!, only: [:index]` to allow the index action in a controller.

### A word of advice.

Good Rails apps are built on REST where you have resources and you usually have the conventional CRUD actions (show, index, create, edit, update, destroy)  that act on the resource. You rarely need additional actions.

And don't be tempted to tuck everything into a limited set of controllers! Do-all controllers is a really bad pattern.

This is an example of a RESTful app layout:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :users
  resources :houses do
    resources :bids
  end
end
```

Run `$ rake routes` to see the routes layout.

Comment: If you are building a real-estate app as I assumed you might want to use the model name `Property` instead of `House` so you don't have to duplicate the logic for houses and flats.